# How can i make this code more robust, fail proof?

Tags: lua

I have some code that needs to update 2 separate databases with user credentials. 
The first database, I just use standard sql to do it.  The second database, I have to use command line scripts to update a specific table. 
What I'm worried about is what to do if the first update fails, or if any of the updates fail. 
Here's what the code looks like right now:

```
local update_password = function(user_id, new_password, session_userid)
   local user = listusers(user_id,nil)
   if #user == 0 then
      return false, "User does not exist"
   else
      sql = "UPDATE users SET password='"..new_password.."', ".."updatedname='"..session_userid.."', updateddatetime="..os.date("%Y%m%d%H%M%S")..createwhereclause(uid)
      runsqlcommand(sql) 
      -- remove user from second db
      local user = {}
      user.descr, user.errtxt = opencmd({"dbctrl", "rm", user_id})     
      if not user.errtext then             
         user.descr, user.errtxt = opencmd({"dbctrl", "add", user_id, new_password}) 
      else   
         result = "Unable to update cdb with new credentials"
         return false, result      
      end
      if not user.errtext then             
         result = "User's password has been updated"     
      else
         result = "Unable to update cdb with new credentials"
         return false, result
      end     
   end
   return true, result
end
```

I guess I should check each step of the way to make sure that the previous sql worked.  So after updating database 1, I should do a select using the new credentials to make sure I get a result. 
But do you have any other suggestions to improve the reliability of this code?
Thanks.